# Why is floating label not working with css

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

I am try to recreate the floating labels from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxRJ8vplzAo&ab_channel=DevEd) tutorial.

when I add this code from the tutorial **(check 15:00 in the tutorial)**

```
.form-group input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form-group input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-120%);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5fa8d3;
}
```

The label loses the floating effect. Check the image below. This state of the label should only be active when the input is `focused`. But for some weird reason this is the default state. This only happens when add `.form-group input:valid + .label-name .content-name` to the code above.

[image]

Here is my full code

```
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #595f6e;
  background-color: #fbf9fa;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.form-group input:focus {
  background-color: #fbf9fa;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.form-group label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5fa8d3;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.content-name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.form-group input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form-group input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-120%);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5fa8d3;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='input-name'>
    <label for="input-name" class='label-name'>
        <span class='content-name'>Enter your name</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have all your css, but with the snippet you gave I was able to get it working by adding the `required` attribute to the `input`.

When you don't have the `required` attribute, the input is always "valid". Therefore, the css selector that had `:valid` was always being applied.

See demo in the snippet below:

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #595f6e;
  background-color: #fbf9fa;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.form-group input:focus {
  background-color: #fbf9fa;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.form-group label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5fa8d3;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.content-name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.form-group input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.form-group input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-120%);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5fa8d3;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='input-name' required>
    <label for="input-name" class='label-name'>
        <span class='content-name'>Enter your name</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working. But is there a reason why we need the `required` attribute?

Comment: @Sashaank here is the explanation from my answer: `When you don't have the required attribute, the input is always "valid". Therefore, the css selector that had :valid was always being applied.`